# SQLite DataAdapter no update or insert

Tags: sqlite, dataadapter

I use Sqlite v1.0.79 and vs2010 to create a simple winform application.

I have a customer table, and want to use the SQLiteDataAdapter to easily insert, update and delete records. So i do not need to type the whole insert, update and delete statements.

So i have a Customer class with a static load function that returns a dataset.

```
  private static SQLiteDataAdapter _Adapter;

  internal static DataSet Load(long id)
  {
     var q = "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE id = {0}".FormatInvariant(id);
     var cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
     cmd.Connection = [_Connection];
     cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
     cmd.CommandTimeout = 10;
     cmd.CommandText = commandText;
     return cmd;         _Adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter();
     _Adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
     var ds = new DataSet();
     _Adapter.Fill(ds, "Customer");
     if (id == 0)
     {
        ds.AddRow(ds.NewRow());
     }
     var b = new SQLiteCommandBuilder(_Adapter);
     _Adapter.AcceptChangesDuringUpdate = true;
     _Adapter.InsertCommand = b.GetInsertCommand();
     _Adapter.UpdateCommand = b.GetUpdateCommand();
     _Adapter.DeleteCommand = b.GetDeleteCommand();

     // Commented out code for note A:
     ////ds.SetRowValue("lastname", "blaat44");
     ////_Adapter.Update(ds, "Customer");

     return ds;
  }
```

After calling the Load method, the DataSet is used in bindings on a windows form. And after some changes, the Save method is called, where the changes supposed to be saved.

```
  internal static void Save(DataSet data)
  {
     //// data.AcceptChanges();
     _Adapter.Update(data, "Customer");
  }
```

But after the update, the database is not updating anything. What am i missing? I already tried the data.AcceptChanges before the update, but nothing works.

btw. the dataset in the save methods does have the 'right' values, but the update or insert is not working....

The strange thing is if i change a field in the dataset in the Load method (the commented out code at Note A in the example above), the data is saved correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Im not an expert and have a basic understanding of sqlite etc but could the problem be that you are passing the dataset to the save function so the adapter is using a copy maybe of the original dataset. Which is why it works in the load method as the adapter is acessing tje original dataset?

Again this maybe complete babble and i may not understand but ive found sometimes the uneducated answer is a very good push in the right direction